# Finding the highest quarter of the year

Tags: oracle-xe

I'm sitting here and do some practise but I just can't find the Solution. Maybe someone could give me some help?

I have a table and should find the highest sale amount of a quarter per year.

**Data table:**

[image: data table]

**My attempt:**

```
SELECT Year, Quarter, MAX(SUM(Revenue)) OVER(PARTITION BY Year)
FROM Sale
GROUP BY Year, Quarter
ORDER BY Year, Quarter;
```

**Output:**

[image: output table]

As you can see the numbers are correct.
But my expected output should be:

```
2012  |  4  |  25
2013  |  2  |  35
```

Would be great if someone has an idea.
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Solution is found.
*Forgot to mention. I used Oracle XE.*

```
SELECT Year, Quarter, QMax
FROM (
  SELECT Year, Quarter,
    MAX(SUM(Revenue)) OVER(PARTITION BY Year) AS QMax,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY SUM(Revenue) DESC) AS QRank
  FROM Sale
  GROUP BY Year, Quarter) QResult
WHERE QRank = 1
ORDER BY Year, Quarter;
```

Comment: In 2013 shoudnt you have 30?

Comment: No, Q2 2013 has 15+20.

Comment: For a start - the answer will depend greatly on the RBDMS server that you're using. MySQL doesn't have the WITH clause as proposed by Rob Farley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Start by getting your quarters:
WITH Qs AS
(SELECT Year, Quarter, SUM(Revenue) AS QRev
 FROM Sale
 GROUP BY Year, Quarter
),
--Now rank them by year
QRanks AS
(SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY QRev DESC) as QRank
 FROM Qs
)
--Now filter
SELECT Year, Quarter, QRev
FROM QRanks
WHERE QRank = 1
ORDER BY Year;
```

Hope this is what you're after. :)

Comment: Tanks for the help! The code didn't work on my machine but you gave me a good structure. Solution posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer is 25 and 30, then this should work

```
SELECT Year, MAX(Quarter) Quarter, MAX(Revenue)
FROM Sale
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year, Quarter
```